# How to fix "This requires the spread-collection experiment to be enable " on latest upgrade of flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I have a code like this

```
SizedBox(height: 10),
        ..._function(context, model),
        SizedBox(height: 5),
        if (model.bloc)
)
```

But after flutter upgrade I have error focus on "..."

```
This requires the spread-collection experiment to be enable
```

How can I rewrite this correctly ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `pubspec.yaml`

change `environment` sdk constraints to:

```
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

Invalidate Caches and Restart your IDE

Android Studio: File>> Invalidate Caches and Restart.

That would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you change your environment to this:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
```

and also do a `Flutter clean` and restart the IDE

**Edited:**

In the root of your project create a file named `analysis_options.yaml` and add these lines to it:

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - spread-collections
```

Comment: No change :(. I was   sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: @Nitneuq did you try adding `analysis_options.yaml` to the root of your project? I had the same issue and after switching to `Stable` flutter channel and changing environment helped me. Also i did a `flutter upgrade`

Comment: I never see or use this ... I use last stable flutter